# i'm trying to solve an equation using gfortran but i keep getting error

Tags: gfortran

i'm using the below program but i keep getting error.What is wrong with my progam?

```
  real x
  complex y
  real m1,H0,Ms,P1,P2,P3,w0,wm,wh
  complex w1,w2,o1,o2
  integer i,n
  real pi
  n=4000000000  
  pi=4*atan(1.0)
  m1=4*pi*1e-7
  H0=39.79e3
  Ms=1400e3
  P1=0.7*0.12
  P2=0.3*0.12
  P3=P1-P2
  w0=m1*(1.76e11)*H0
  wm=m1*(1.76e11)*Ms
  wh=w0-P3*wm
  im=cmplx(0,1)
  w1=wm/2+wh-im*0.06*2*pi*x
  w2=wm/2-wh-im*0.06*2*pi*x
  o1=x**2-x*(2*wh-(P3*wm)/2)-w1*w2+(wm/2)*(P1*w2+P2*w1)
  o2=x**2+x*(2*wh-(P3*wm)/2)-w1*w2+(wm/2)*(P1*w2+P2*w1)

  do i=0,n
     x=i
     y=1+wm*(P1*w1*((w2)**2-x**2))/(o1*o2)
 &        +wm*(P2*w2*((w1)**2-x**2))/(o1*o2)
 &        -wm*((wm/2)*((P1*w2+P2*w1)**2)))/(o1*o2)
 &        +wm*((wm/2)*((P3*x)**2))/(o1*o2)
     write(10,*)x,y
  enddo
  return
  end
```

Comment: what's the error?  don't make people read and compile your program to find out.  how 'bout some background?  what's the equation?  what's the solution method?  read this, please: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Well, for first, you can't have a return statement in the main program.

Answer (score 4):

This line (the third in the multiline statement):

```
-wm*((wm/2)*((P1*w2+P2*w1)**2)))/(o1*o2)
    ||    | ||           |   ||| |     |
    |+----+ |+-----------+   ||| +-----+
    |       +----------------+||
    +-------------------------+|
??? <--------------------------+
```

has one too many closing parentheses {tremble in fear at my awesome drawing skills :-) }. It should be:

```
-wm*((wm/2)*((P1*w2+P2*w1)**2))/(o1*o2)
```

---

The *full* list of problems I got from that source was:

```
source.f90:7.18: n=4000000000
                             1
                 Error: Integer too big for its kind at (1). This check can
                 be disabled with the option -fno-range-check.
source.f90:26.9: y=1+wm*(P1*w1*((w2)**2-x**2))/(o1*o2) &
                 1
                 Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

The second of those is the one you're probably having (and the one you can fix with the above solution). The first, if you're having it, will cause a problem but I suspect it's just because of my environment.

Comment: Anybody that good at spotting unbalanced parentheses must also be a lisp programmer